# npm run dev with Nodejs only?

Tags: node.js, laravel, npm, vue.js, ovh

I develop my website on my computer with Laravel and VueJS. On my computer I can run `npm run dev` without problems.

When I commit to Github my website, there is a webhook that runs a script on my hosting to update the real website (on OVH).

My hosting his is a shared hosting (OVH) with SSH access, there is NodeJS available but not NPM.

How could I run `npm run dev` from my shared hosting ? Is there a way to run this with NodeJS ?

Thanks.

Comment: ask your provider to install `npm`

Comment: If you just want to execute the `dev` script defined in the `package.json` file, maybe you can do something like `bash -c $(node -e 'console.log(require("./package.json").scripts.dev)')` (untested).

Comment: I suppose you should not run `npm run dev` on the production server. Consider building VueJS code using `npm run build` and publishing built version to the production.

Comment: @Toumaniere hi, do u hv a solution to this already?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to install npm locally, rather than system wide.

NVM (https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm), for example, seems to do the job (disclaimer : I haven't used it yet, I am just looking for a way to set up node/npm without changing my system wide version).

This specific tool will install node and npm somewhere in your `$HOME`, and additionally tinker your `.bashrc` so that commands like `node` and `npm` point to the correct scripts or wrappers.

If you have several users on your hosted server, you should make sure that these wrappers are used for your other users too.